# What are persistent segment trees and how do I use them?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree

I have come across a lot of problems which could be solve using persistent segment trees but I can't seem to understand this concept.

I have found some resources but I still can't understand it.

Comment: Which don't you understand? Segment trees or persistence?

Answer (score 0):

You can view this link about segment trees http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/15890